# query data that some values change

Tags: mysql, compare

I have data in a DB and I try to check what's different about the data between today and yesterday.

```
     select distinct prefix_id,node_name,prefix_cidr 
     FROM tableA AS old 
     WHERE import_date = '2017-03-06' 
     AND prefix_cidr 
     IN 
         (SELECT prefix_cidr 
         FROM tableA 
         WHERE old.import_date <> import_date 
         AND old.prefix_cidr = prefix_cidr 
         AND node_name <> old.node_name)
```

//query data that is same ip values but different import date and node values

I get the following result but it is not correct. 
ex:

```
2017-03-01|x.x.x.x|AAA
2017-03-06|x.x.x.x|AAA
```

The following is the result that I need
ex:

```
2017-03-01|x.x.x.x|AAA
2017-03-06|x.x.x.x|BBB
```

I get the data when the node has changed

this is my data

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/xomO7.png*

Comment: maybe you need to post your table(s) schema for others to understand what you have

Comment: @Yazan, I added image as your suggest. Hope this help other understand my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you need something in that direction:

```
SELECT distinct 
 old.prefix_id
 , old.node_name
 , old.prefix_cidr
 , new.prefix_id
 , new.node_name
 , new.prefix_cidr 
FROM tableA AS old, tableA AS new
WHERE old.import_date = '2017-03-06' 
 AND old.import_date <> new.import_date 
 AND old.prefix_cidr = new.prefix_cidr 
 AND old.node_name <> new.node_name
```

Comment: Thank you. this is correct query for my question. :)

Comment: Then please mark it also as, I need the points, I need them ;).

Comment: Sorry, I can't do it. because system don't allow. :(

Comment: Sad thing, then hack it! ;)